# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email filled with data from the form. Currently trying to do with Gmail, the goal is to send from the local server. But it throws me an exception. I have added `.jar` into lib. Sorry if the question is stupid, im novice.

How to fix it step by step?

```java
    public void sendMail(String from, String password, String recipient, FormModel formModel) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
                }
            });


            Message message = pmessage(session, from, recipient);
            try {
                Transport.send(message);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private Message pmessage(Session session, String myaccount, String recipient) {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            try {
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myaccount));
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
                message.setSubject("formular");
                message.setText("TEST");
                return message;
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    }
```

[image]
lib
[image]
**Expected output is sent mail.**

Comment: 1) paste exception 2) what jar did you add 3) if it is correct jar, it is probably not on classpath.

Comment: @Antoniossss thx ive made changes in question

Comment: So its not on the classpath. How to change that is dependent on how you run application.

Comment: @Antoniossss im using intellij idea 2019, im running with (Shift+F10)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following. Worked for me earlier for a similar issue:

- Along with mail.jar add the activation.jar to your classpath.
  [http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar]

OR

- Click File from the toolbar
- Project Structure
- Select Modules at the left panel
- Dependencies tab Select '+' → JARs or directories